# Closed form solution to $\int_0^1\arctan^2(x)\,\sqrt{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, trigonometry

I need to compute this integral:
$$\int_0^1\arctan^2(x)\,\sqrt{x}\,dx$$
I tried integration by parts, and also introducing a parameter $\arctan(a\,x)$ and differentiation wrt it, but these approaches did not lead to anything useful. Please help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this integral is simple

Comment: Ben Longo is right. This is not a simple integral, and as such, you will not find a simple answer.

Comment: I think that the integral is equivalent to $$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n+3} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n(2k-1)}\right]$$
but I have no idea how to tackle this. The numerical estimates are the same.

Comment: This question, as written, would be improved by including the *motivation*: why is this particular integral of interest, out of the infinite number of integrals that could be computed?

Comment: @CarlMummert It is of interest for exploring the space of integrals that have a nice closed form of course :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integrand has a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions and dilogarithms. *Mathematica* can find it if we help it by first converting the arctangent into a combination of logarithms:
$$\arctan(x)=\frac i2\ln(1-i x)-\frac i2\ln(1+ix)$$
After some simplifications it takes [this form](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/680fae6f01a10938e10f/raw/030f248a22d89efc4df5d3d2643c4b7468db7aab/Antiderivative.nb). Its correctness can be checked manually using direct differentiation. Plugging the integration limits and performing some simplifications, we get the same result as given by Cleo.

Comment: This solution method has the appeal of being nice and systematic, plus it gives you an easy way to eyeball integrands and tell in advance whether an antiderivative at least exists before going through the tedium of calculating it. However, as they say on late night tv, THERE'S GOT TO BE A BETTER WAY! A major downside is that the huge polylog expressions generated this way tend to be too much for WolframAlpha, so mathers like me w/o a Mathematica license are  are out of luck. :'(

Comment: @DavidH I think the *Wolfram Mathematica Online Integrator* is definitely for you. This is a free online tool by Wolfram for integrating, and sometimes goes further then WolframAlpha. You could find Vladimir's solution [here](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28I*Log[1-I*x]%2F2-I*Log[1%2BI*x]%2F2%29^2*Sqrt[x]&random=false). I think the output is the same as what the `Integrate` function gives in *Mathematica*, so this is a pure solution without further simplification.

Comment: @user153012 Yes, this is how the antiderivative looks before simplification. Unfortunately, [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) for this expression takes a long time, and does not do much of improvement. I simplified it using handwritten rules, and it took a lot of effort to reach the final form.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, I also believe there got to be a better way. There should be an explanation for massive cancellations that occur when one tries to simplify the antiderivative.

Answer (score 29):

$$\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{2\pi}3+\frac1{36\sqrt{2}}\left[5\pi^2+12\left(4+\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt2}2\right)\right)\left(\pi-2\ln\left(1+\sqrt2\right)\right)-48\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\sqrt2-1\right)\right]$$

Comment: ...how was this achieved?

Answer (score 2):

The integration range is small: $[0, 1]$ so one of the method could be to use Taylor series for the $\arctan(x)$ function:

$$\arctan^2(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\sum_{m = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)}x^{2n+1}x^{2m+1}$$

And write $\sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ to obtain:

$$I = \int_0^1\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)}x^{2n+1}x^{2m+1} x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

namely

$$I = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)}\int_0^1x^{2n+1}x^{2m+1} x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

That will lead you to (after a trivial integration)

$$I = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (-1)^m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)}\frac{1}{\left(2(n+m) + \frac{7}{2}\right)}$$